# option onsubmit and alert not working together

Tags: javascript, php

What I am looking for is a simple way of having a form with a set of options to give an alert if the default entry is chosen, but to have the correct set of links open correctly in a new tab or window.

When creating an `onsubmit` event to open a new window for a link within a form works fine by itself, but is not working together with an alert.

Here is the issue.  I have a simple option select pulling data from a database, and `onsubmit` it works fine to open this link in a new tab or window.    This code below works for all links that exist

```
<form method="get" name="dbs" onsubmit="window.open(link.value,'_blank');return false" >

<select name="link" class="required">'
<option value="blank" selected disabled="disabled">Select a specific database from the following:</option>

<?php    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['url'] . '" >'. $row['source_name'] . '</option>';
}
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

**However**, the problem is with the first default selected row.  It, of course, brings up a 404 error in the new window.

I have been attempting to run a function that will give an alert if a user attempts to submit the first default option ("Select a specific.. etc")

Here is what I have tried.

I created this function to validate the entry:

```
function checkSubmit() {

    if (document.getElementsByName('link')[0].value == 'blank' ) {

        alert('Please select a database'); return false
    }

}
```

However I have been having a hard time getting the two onsubmits to work together.  I tried this:

```
<form method="get" name="dbs" onsubmit="checkSubmit() && window.open(link.value,'_blank');return false" >
```

and the function works fine but nothing at all happens when I choose a legitimate link.

If I change the `&&` to `&`, `||`, or `|`, the alert works, but after clicking okay, it brings up the **404**, however the legitimate links work.  ***This is the closest I have come***, but I want the alert to simply stop the form, and only work if the first entry is *not* chosen.

I tried moving the onsubmit into the function and like so:

```
function checkSubmit() {

    if (document.getElementsByName('link')[0].value == 'blank' ) {

        alert('Please select a database'); return false
    }
    else {
      window.open(link.value,'_blank');return false
    }

}
```

and the alert again works fine, however the `else` does not work at all for legit links:  it just refreshes the page with no action at all.

I'm hoping for some pointers.  I'd like it to simply give an alert if someone picks the first option value, but not for the rest.  I also do not want the page to refresh (hence the `return false` lines).

Comment: try this,
var win = window.open(link.value, '_blank');  
        win.focus(); return false;

Comment: Did you mean in the function?  Unfortunately, still no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you just need to `return true` inside the function.

```
function checkSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementsByName('link')[0].value == 'blank' ) {
        alert('Please select a database');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What was happening before was either `false` or `undefined` was being returned to the first section of the `&&`. Because both are falsy values, the second part was never reached.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be simple, and this was making me crazy.